# Unicode Ø symbol with superscript in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, symbols

I would like to put the following text behind the ggplot chart

[image]

And I thought it should be very easy to achieve. Unfortunately, all my attempts ended in a complete failure.
I have already read over a dozen posts on this forum that dealt with this topic. I have already made several dozen attempts and still do not manage to get the effect I expect.
By the way, I noticed a rather strange treatment of unicode symbols. Please compare the title and subtitle from the chart below.

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot()+
  labs(
    title = expression("\u00AE \u00A9, \u00A2, \u00BC, \u00BD, \u00BE, \u00A5, \u00D8, \u00F8"),
    subtitle = "\u00AE \u00A9, \u00A2, \u00BC, \u00BD, \u00BE, \u00A5, \u00D8, \u00F8"
  )+
  annotate(geom="text", label="\u00D828.15^{+0.15}", x=0, y=0.08,parse = TRUE, size=5)+
  annotate(geom="text", label="\u00D8", x=0, y=0, size=5)+
  annotate(geom="text", label="28.15^{+0.15}", x=0.03, y=0.001,parse = TRUE, size=5)+
  xlim(c(-0.1, 0.1))+
  ylim(c(-0.02, 0.1))+
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Why do some unicode symbols lose some of their graphics when placed inside an `expression` function or when I use the `parse` option? This happens with the symbols ¢, ¥, ¼, ½, ¾, Ø. In my case, I particularly care about the symbol Ø. I finally got the effect on the track chart (annotation at the bottom of the chart) was created from the tedious setting of two annotations next to each other. However, it completely falls apart as soon as I change the size of the chart.

Does anyone know how this can be solved?

Thank you very much for your quick reply. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work for me! :-(

```
library(latex2exp)
library(ggplot2)
label <- TeX("$Ø28.15^{+0.15}$")
qplot(1, "A") +
  annotate(geom = "text", label = label, x = 1, y = 1.1, size = 10) +
  xlab(label)
```

[image]

Comment: Seems platform dependent.  I get correct rendering with R 4.0.2 on Linux.

Comment: I use RStudion Version 1.4.1717 in Windows 7 Prof and R version 4.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LaTeX syntax within a math (`$`) environment to auto-generate the plotmath expression:

```r
library(latex2exp)
library(ggplot2)

label <- TeX("$Ø28.15^{+0.15}$")
label
#> expression(`$Ø28.15^{+0.15}$` = paste("", "Ø28", ".", "15", 
#>     phantom()^{
#>         paste("+0", ".", "15")
#>     }, ""))

qplot(1, "A") +
  annotate(geom = "text", label = label, x = 1, y = 1.1, size = 10) +
  xlab(label)
#> Warning in is.na(x): is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type
#> 'expression'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-10-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work for me! :-(   Please see my question update.

Comment: This is an encoding issue of your particular system. What happens if you export this plot as pdf using cairo? `ggsave(p, filename = 'plot.pdf', device = cairo_pdf)`

Comment: I get exactly the same effect with O.

Comment: Then it is an issue of your system. Try searching for terms like encoding error in plotting unicode character in windows. Your language and localization settings of Windows might also matter.

Comment: It amazes me a bit. If there really was a problem with my system, I wouldn't be able to get characters like ¥, ¼, ½, ¾. Please note that when I don't use the `expression` function everything is fine (subtitle of the first graph). On the other hand, when I use `expression` the characters are not displayed completely. For example, instead of ¾ I get 3, instead of ¥ I get Y and instead of Ø I get O. As if the function in `expression` changes the graphics of these characters for some reason. However, characters such as ® or © are printed correctly.

Comment: Try `options(encoding = "utf8")` before plotting. Seems that the bits used to define ¾ in utf-8 maps to 3 in your encoding locale.

Comment: I had `encoding = "utf8 "` set. But I tried again nevertheless. Unfortunately, without the expected effect.

Comment: I prefer to isolate my R environments using docker so that they do not interfere with the systems settings. I recommend to run this in the container image `rocker/verse`.

Comment: I do not really understand. What does "run this in the container image" mean?

Comment: There is Docker desktop for windows. You can run a pre-configured box (container) called rocker/verse inside your computer which comes with its own packages and encoding settings. We can not help you further, because we do not know every detail of your system settings. The issue can be anywhere. Docker containers are standardized environments so that everyone has exactly the same system to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I know how to modify this solution above, maybe not so cute, but works everywhere

```
library(ggplot2)
label <- "\u00D828.15\U207A\u2070\U00B7\U00B9\u2075" 
 qplot(1, "A") +
     annotate(geom = "text", label = label, x = 1, y = 1.1, size = 10) +
     xlab(label)
```

[image]